# Rim lighting in glass sphere? light inside doesnt work?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, glass

I am trying to achieve this effect with my smooth shaded spheres, but if the sphere had the glossiness of glass with something inside it: https://dribbble.com/shots/3889660-Siri-assistant-AR-Hologram

I have my spheres with a low IOR for a weird bulging effect, and put emissive objects inside. I need to achieve (just on the rim really) that emissive colored look, to differentiate the sphere from the environment.

So I put a point light inside, but no matter the brightness nothing looks different  aside from maybe that white reflection there:

[image]

How can I achieve an emissive glow around the outer rim?

Comment: Try halo on vertices forming the circle that halves your sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do makes no sense (to me) from a physical point of view ([Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations)), so I would use a node setup to "fake it". [image: node setup]

The texture you plug into the color input of the emssion should resemble the texture of the emission object inside (I used a noise texture for demonstration purposes).

Comment: Awesome! Is there an easy way to specifically PICK the colors? I know you're doing Hue/Sat but can I pick specifics somehow?

Comment: Hue/Sat node is just there to oversaturate the noise texture and make the effect more visible. You can cut the line from the hue/sat node to the Color input (Yellow) of the Emission node and either plug in a texture of your own or choose a color directly by clicking on the white field beside "Color".